# Infinitely iterated square roots in groups

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a group. What are possible conditions on $G$ to ensure that there is no sequence $\{g_i\}_{i\in\mathbb Z}\subset G\backslash\{1\}$ such that $g_{i+1}=g_i^2$ for all $i\in\mathbb Z$?

Does finitely-generated torsion free work?

Comment: Finitely generated torsion free does not work, witness the solvable Baumslag-Solitar group $BS(2,1) = \langle a,t \bigm| tat^{-1}=a^2 \rangle$.